# Issue in running awk command

Tags: bash, awk

I was asked this question:

> A File has five lines below where (blank) means a blank line:
>
> ```
> alpha
> (blank)
> beta
> (blank)
> alpha beta
> ```
>
> Based on this, which of the following will be the output when the bash command below is executed?
>
> ```
> cat file | awk 'BEGIN ( n=0 ) /^$/ ( n+=1 ) END ( print "n=" n%2*3 )'
> ```

When I tried to create the file and run the above command I, got so many errors:

```
sh-4.2$ cat test.txt | awk 'BEGIN ( n=0 ) /^$/ ( n+=1 ) END ( print "n=" n%2*3 )'                                                                               
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN ( n=0 ) /^$/ ( n+=1 ) END ( print "n=" n%2*3 )                                                                                          
awk: cmd. line:1:       ^ syntax error                                                                                                                          
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN ( n=0 ) /^$/ ( n+=1 ) END ( print "n=" n%2*3 )                                                                                          
awk: cmd. line:1:                ^ syntax error                                                                                                                 
awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN ( n=0 ) /^$/ ( n+=1 ) END ( print "n=" n%2*3 )                                                                                          
awk: cmd. line:1:                   ^ unterminated regexp
```

Can you please help me what the awk command is doing and why I am getting all these errors?

I am using online [unix shell](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_bash_online.php) prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got the braces all wrong for the `awk` syntax, you need `{}` in-place of `()`

```
awk 'BEGIN {n=0} /^$/ { n+=1 }END{print "n=" n%2*3}' file
```

and you don't need to use `cat` without any purpose here, `Awk` is perfectly capable of processing on files directly.

What the command does is,

1. In general `awk` processes file contents one line at a time. The statements within `BEGIN{}` clause gets runs before the processing of the file happens, so any actions to initializing variables are done here.
2. `/^$/` is a `regEx` syntax for match a `blank` line, so as `Awk` processes input lines if it sees a blank line the part `{ n+=1 }` increments the count of those blank occurrences.
3. So by the time `awk` is done processing the file, the value of `n` will be `2`
4. The `END` is a similar clause which gets run after all the input lines are processed. So here usually we do manipulation of the variable/array contents stored as part of the file processing. Here we just print the value of `n` by doing a modulo of `2` then multiplying that value with `3`

Comment: Thanks, can you please help me in understanding what the command is doing?

Comment: You can get rid of `BEGIN {n=0}` as it's doing nothing useful.